# Вывод переменных из массива

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, вывод

Требуется найти сумму и произведение элементов массива(условия в коде) и вывести переменные произведения и суммы

```
        {
           string noelem = "Элементов не найдено";
           int sum = 0;
           int pr = 1;
           int[] mas = new int[TB1.Lines.Length];
           //
           for (int i = 1; i < mas.Length; i++)
               mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(TB1.Lines[i]);
           //
           for (int i = 1; i < mas.Length; i++)
               if (mas[i] < 50)
                   pr *= mas[i];
               else 
               if (mas[i] > 100)
                   sum += mas[i];
           //
           for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
               if (pr == 1) TB2.Text = noelem.ToString();
               else
                   mas[i] = pr;
           }
           for (int i = 2; i < 3; i++) {
               mas[i] = sum;
           }
               //
               TB2.Clear();
           for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
           if (pr == 1) TB2.Text = noelem.ToString();
           else
               TB2.AppendText(mas[i] + Environment.NewLine);
           for (int i = 2; i < 3; i++)
               if (sum == 0) TB3.Text = noelem.ToString();
           else
           TB3.AppendText(mas[i] + Environment.NewLine);
       }
```

Если преобразование массива это не лучший способ

```cs
for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
               if (pr == 1) TB2.Text = noelem.ToString();
               else
                   mas[i] = pr;
           }
           for (int i = 2; i < 3; i++) {
               mas[i] = sum;
           }
```

Тогда как вообще выводить переменные?(Лучше ответ с примером)

Comment: В другой ListBox.

Comment: @becouse, почему "ListBox", когда вывод только в компонент TextBox

Comment: Так вы же программу пишите. Создайте еще компонентов. Вообще сделайте две Label. Одну для отображения суммы, вторую для произведения.

Comment: @becouse, Хорошо, попробую. Но я конечно малоопытный и вообще студент-первокурсник, но по-моему Label это только подпись для окна TextBox

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/label-control-windows-forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
  TB2.Text = (pr == 1)? noelem: pr.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
  TB2.AppendText((sum == 0)? noelem: sum.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
```

Вероятно, с точки зрения понятности интерфейса лучше будет сделать пару Label, в каждую выводить значение с пояснением, что это такое. Типа `sum: 3`, вывод сделать через `Format`

Comment: Тогда последний вопрос, Преобразование массива НЕиспользовать? Ну, я про `for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
               if (pr == 1) TB2.Text = noelem.ToString();
               else
                   mas[i] = pr;
           }
           for (int i = 2; i < 3; i++) {
               mas[i] = sum;
           }`

Comment: Конечно, не использовать. Результат вычислений  (pr, sum) в большинстве случаев должен быть логически отделён от источника данных (mas)